# How to access this specific JSON key

Tags: json, file, object, key

This is my JSON file from which I want to access `"tr_name"` which is inside var  `InspectorDefs` but I can't find the way.Any help please?

JSON FILE:

```
var InspectorDefs = {

    'link': {

        inputs: {
            attrs: {
                '.attributes': {
                    'tr_name': { type: 'text',  group: 'attributes', label: 'Name', index: 1 },
                    'tr_description': { type: 'text',  group: 'attributes', label: 'Description', index: 2 },
                    'tr_rules': { type: 'select', options: [], group: 'attributes', label: 'Rule', index: 3 },
                    'tr_value': { type: 'select', options: ['true', 'false'], group: 'attributes', label: 'Value', index: 4 },
                    'tr_rule_source': { type: 'select', options: ['BPM', 'Drools', 'iLog'], group: 'attributes', label: 'Rule source', index: 5 }

                },
            },
        },
    },



};
```

I want to pass `tr_name` path here but I am desperate:

```
cell.on('change:tr_name', function(cell, change, opt) {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are just looking for how to access your properties in javascript then you would reference it like this

```
InspectorDefs.link.inputs.attrs[".attributes"].tr_description
```

JSON objects can be referenced as properties or dictionaries, i am assuming you are having issues with the ".attributes"?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxrzne2n/)

Comment: You are 100% right about the access of tr_description. I still have problems with my implementation of cell.on('change:tr_description', function(cell, change, opt) {}) but irrespective that you answered my question regarding what I asked for , so I will check your answer as a final  answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [] as in array or map.

```
  var tr_name = InspectorDefs['link']['inputs']['attrs']['.attributes']['tr_name'];
```

But in your case I guess you want to call some function when the attribute of some html tag changed. so you can use the actual html tag generated by this json file which can be found from the web page generated or from my guess it is: `<Name>` tag as read from the json file

Comment: Thanks for helping me but I found my problem.Now it works great.